# performing function based on string value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uisegmentedcontrol

I am new to objective-c.I am having one string which contains value like 0,13,5.. Now i am trying to perform various functions by using the value.

Here is my code.

```
NSString*  statusfield = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tmpDict objectForKey:@"StatusId"]];
if([statusfield isEqualToString:@"13"])
{
    [cell.mySegmentedControl setTitle:@"SEND TO ADMIN" forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [cell.mySegmentedControl setTitle:@"EVALUATE" forSegmentAtIndex:1];
}
if([statusfield isEqualToString:@"5"])
{
   [cell.mySegmentedControl setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:0];
   [cell.mySegmentedControl setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:1];
}

if([statusfield  isEqualToString: @"1"])
{
    [cell.mySegmentedControl setTitle:@"ACCEPT" forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [cell.mySegmentedControl setTitle:@"REJECT" forSegmentAtIndex:1];
}
if([statusfield isEqualToString:@"3"])
{
    [cell.mySegmentedControl setTitle:@"VIEW" forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [cell.mySegmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:UISegmentedControlNoSegment];
}
```

The first string and last string contains 3. So it shows duplicates in my segmented control. I want to check the exact condition.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you can share the screenshot as well (i haven't down voted you).

Comment: There is no need to attach the screen shot. I am asking for the logic to check the condition based on the string value.

Comment: " first string and last string contains 3": Shouldn't matter since you do `isEqualToString:` and not `containsString:`. Also, you could use a switch case: `NSUInteger status = [[tmpDict objectForKey:@"StatusId"] integerValue]; switch(status):{case 3:{//Do you stuff}break; case 5:{//Do you stuff} break;} etc.`

Comment: in your case use `else if` or `switch` to authenticate one among many blocks of code, using only `if` checks every condition after match.

Comment: @vaibhav `else/if` is indeed better (optimized) than `if` in that case, but since it's using `isEqualToString:` it shouldn't enter two if test: only one or zero.

Comment: please post how you are getting `[tmpDict objectForKey:@"StatusId"]];`

Comment: @Larme suggested the same, you are correct but it will check every condition in case of `if`.

Comment: @vaibhav okay thanks

Answer (score 0):

the below one worked for me:

```
NSString*  statusfield = @"3";

    if([statusfield isEqualToString:@"13"])
    {
        NSLog(@"13 executed");
    }
    if([statusfield isEqualToString:@"5"])
    {
        NSLog(@"5 executed");
    }

    if([statusfield  isEqualToString: @"1"])
    {
      NSLog(@"1 executed");
    }
    if([statusfield isEqualToString:@"3"])
    {
        NSLog(@"3 executed");
    }
```

I got log like below

```
//  3 executed
```

Comment: i think the result is same using only `if` with `isEqualToString` method but here execution diff using `else if`?